# Format a text file in python when it finds a specific work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to format a text file from an api request output. So far my code looks like such:

```
import requests

url = 'http://URLhere.com'
headers = {'tokenname': 'tokenhash'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,)

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(response.text)
```

and this creates a text file but the output is on one line.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Have it start a new line every time the code reaches a certain word like "id","status", or "closed_at" but unfortunately I have not been able to figure this out.
2. Also I am trying to get a count of how many "id" there are in the file but I think due to the formatting, the script does not like it.

The output is as follows:

```
{
    [
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "status": "open or close",
            "closed_at": null,
            "created_at": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ",
            "due_date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
            "notes": null,
            "port": [pnumber
            ],
            "priority": 1,
            "identifiers": [
                "12345"
            ],
            "last_seen_time": "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ",
            "scanner_score": 1.0,
            "fix_id": 12345,
            "scanner_vulnerabilities": [
                {
                    "port": null,
                    "external_unique_id": "12345",
                    "open": false
                }
            ],
            "asset_id": 12345
```

This continues on one line with the same names but for different assets.

Comment: You'll have to give a sample of output.

Comment: That code won't work. It's missing a colon and not properly indented.

Comment: @khelwood yes you are correct I was in fact missing a colon and indent in this post but be assured I do have that in my code.

Comment: You question is about response.text formatting when written to file, then you need to provide sample data you find in your response.text in order for others to help you.

Comment: @najeem the output looks something to the extent of this: 
"{[{"id":12345,"status":"open or close","closed_at":null,"created_at":"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ","due_date":"yyyy-mm-dd","notes":null,"port":[pnumber],"priority":1,"identifiers":["12345"],"last_seen_time":"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.msmsmsZ","scanner_score":1.0,"fix_id":12345,"scanner_vulnerabilities":[{"port":null,"external_unique_id":"12345","open":false}],"asset_id":12345"

this continues on only one line and I am hoping to learn to separate by certain words as mentioned in the output

Comment: @andnik I was commenting the output as you responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code :

```
with open ('text.txt') as text_file :
    data = text_file.read ()
    print ('\n'.join (data.split (',')))
```

Gives this output :

```
"{[{"id":12345
"status":"open or close"
"closed_at":null
"created_at":"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ"
"due_date":"yyyy-mm-dd"
"notes":null
"port":[pnumber]
"priority":1
"identifiers":["12345"]
"last_seen_time":"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.msmsmsZ"
"scanner_score":1.0
"fix_id":12345
"scanner_vulnerabilities":[{"port":null
"external_unique_id":"12345"
"open":false}]
"asset_id":12345"
```

And then to write it to a new file :

```
output = data.split (',')
with open ('new.txt', 'w') as write_file :
    for line in output :
        write_file.write (line + '\n')
```

Comment: This code actually solves one of the issues I was unable to do, which was separating the output on different lines. Thank you but now I am seeing if I can count how many times certain names show up like "id", "status", or "closed_at"

Comment: How do I get this output in a text file? Every time I attempt to write this into a file it puts it back to one line but if used as print, it shows up perfectly.

Comment: @jeffpierce I've add writing to a new file to my answer.